# Determine if two coordinates are within desired radius

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on aggregating my city's main big intersections with my city's collision data. What am trying to accomplish is to determine the number of accidents which happened in and around the intersection within a 20 meters radius.

Luckily, I'm already far off in the project and I have two tables in my database `intersections` and `collisions`

My `intersections` table:

```
 --------------------------------------------
 |  id  |  city  |  Latitude  |  Longitude  |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  1   |   1    |   34.44444 |   84.3434   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  2   |   1    | 42.4666667 | 1.4666667   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  3   |   1    |  32.534167 | 66.078056   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  4   |   1    |  36.948889 | 66.328611   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  5   |   1    |  35.088056 | 69.046389   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  6   |   1    |  36.083056 |   69.0525   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  7   |   1    |  31.015833 | 61.860278   |
 --------------------------------------------
```

MY `collisions` table:

```
--------------------------------------------
 |  id  |  cause |  Latitude  |  Longitude  |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  1   |   1    |   44.44444 |   81.3434   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  2   |   1    | 32.4666667 | 1.4666667   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  3   |   1    |  42.534167 | 63.078056   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  4   |   1    |  46.948889 | 62.328611   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  5   |   1    |  45.088056 | 61.046389   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  6   |   1    |  46.083056 |   63.0525   |
 --------------------------------------------
 |  7   |   1    |  41.015833 | 69.860278   |
 --------------------------------------------
```

Note: Some fields were omitted for simplicity sake

As you can see, both tables posses `latitude` and `longitude` fields. Now to determine if ***intersection*** and ***collision*** coordinates are close, I thought of using a MySQL query that takes an id of an ***intersection*** which then queries the `collisions` table to get all collisions within 20 meters of the ***intersection***.

What is this query (in MySQL or in Sequelize)?

Here's what I have now (it's in Sequelize using a MySQL database)

```
// api/collisions/{intersection_id}/count

exports.intersection_accident_count = (req, res) => {
    intersection.findOne({where: {equipement: req.params.intersection_id}}).then(intersection => {

        let intersectionLongitude = intersection.longitude;
        let intersectionLatitude = intersection.latitude;

        collision.count({where: {
            longitude: {
                $gt: intersectionLongitude
            },
            latitude: {
                $gt: intersectionLatitude
            },
        }}).then(count => {
            res.status(200).json({'number_of_accidents': count});
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with straightforward way:

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    intersections AS i
    INNER JOIN collisions AS c ON (
        ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(i.Longitude, i.Latitude), POINT(c.Longitude, c.Latitude)) < @dist
    )
```

This should give you results, however the query will not use any indexes at all and if you have many records it would be very slow.

You should think of adding geometry data types in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `collisions` ADD COLUMN `Location` POINT;
UPDATE `collisions` SET Location = POINT(Longitude, Latitude);
ALTER TABLE `intersections` ADD COLUMN `Location` POINT;
UPDATE `intersections` SET Location = POINT(Longitude, Latitude);
```

You can add trigger so the Location will be populated automatically when you updating Longitude/Latitude.

Then:

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    intersections AS i
    INNER JOIN collisions AS c ON (
        ST_Distance_Sphere(i.Location, c.Location) < @dist
    )
```

This would be a bit faster.

If you'd like to make it even faster, you can add another geometry poligon `Area` column into your intersection table and 'pre-build' areas (can be round for accuracy or square for speed).
After that you will be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    intersections AS i
    INNER JOIN collisions AS c ON (
        ST_WITHIN(c.Location, i.Area)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But do you think it's better I create a new table that aggregates both models and I use a javascript method to determine if the collisions are within radius? I just taught of that

Comment: Nope. Intersections and collisions are different things and they will have different properties. So you should not merge them into a single table just because both have location coordinates. Also, I believe that this calculation should be done by server. However, this depend on your application and a number or records.

Comment: I don't mean merging them, but rather a mapping table that has the ids of both tables and if the ids are in a row, it means that the collision happened in the intersection

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand why in case the ids are in a row, this means that the collision is on the intersection.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit tired, what I meant is: I'll use a function written in javascript that takes as parameters the coordinates of one collision and one intersection. The function will check if the given collision is within 20 meters of the intersection, if it is, it will create a new row in the mapping table with both ids (the intersection_id and the collision_id)

Comment: Sure, you can do this. ST_Distance_Sphere/ST_Distance do exactly the same -- they calculate distance between 2 points. As all data is in DB I'd process it on DB level as well (it would be faster, can be updated by trigger on insert/update). Would you like to "cache" the results in a separate table -- different story. I would not do this from beginning as almost any other premature optimisation.